# Is there a way to check if exactly 4 strings out of 5 strings are equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 5 strings. 4 are the same, lets say they're all `'K'` and one is different, `'J'`. Is there a way to compare all of them and check if exactly 4 out of the 5 are equal.

Pseudo code:

```
rc1 = 'K'
rc2 = 'J'
rc3 = 'K'
rc4 = 'K'
rc5 = 'K'

if four are the same from rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4 or rc5:
    print error
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not consistent with your title (*"exactly 4"* or *"at least 4"*?) but this will print an error if not all of them are the same:

```
if len(set([rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4, rc5])) > 1:
    print("Error")
```

Update: If you need to check if exactly *n* of them are the same, something like this would work:

```
items = [rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4, rc5]
n = 4
if any(items.count(item) == n for item in items):
    print("{} of them are the same, {} is different".format(n, len(items) - n))
```

or you can actually calculate the most repeating element:

```
max_repeat = max(items.count(item) for item in items)
print("{} of them are the same".format(max_repeat))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the list is of size 5, this is equivalent to checking if the first or the second item in the list occur exactly 4 times. You can do this by using `list.count` twice:

```
def AreFourItemsEqual(l):
    return l.count(l[0]) == 4 or l.count(l[1]) == 4

if AreFourItemsEqual([rc1,rc2,rc3,rc4,rc5]):
    print ("Error")
```

Comment: It's not the most efficient way of doing it, but it's concise.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for a dictionary:

```
rc1 = 'K'
rc2 = 'J'
rc3 = 'K'
rc4 = 'K'
rc5 = 'K'
strs = [rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4, rc5]

def four_out_of_five_match(strs):
    d = {}
    for str in strs:
        d[str] = d.get(str, 0) + 1
        if d[str] == 4:
            return True
    return False

print(four_out_of_five_match(strs))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from itertools import groupby

strs = [rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4, rc5]
count = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(strs)]
if 4 in count or 5 in count:
    print('error')
```

You get the number of occurrence of the strings with groupby. I think this method is more general.